# QDesktopServices::storageLocation returns admin folder after elevating program

Tags: c++, windows, qt, uac

parts of my application suite (client + updater) needs administrator rights for correct behaviour. My client application uses QDesktopServices::storageLocation() in various places to get the correct user profile path for saving user specific data. But as soon as im using QDesktopService::storageLocation() in an elevated application the path changes to the admin user, which makes it difficult to control.

Like from "C:\Users\basic_user\AppData\Local" to "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local".

Is there a way to deal with this with qt or is my only possibility to use the WinApi?

What is the "right way" when facing the scenario of having an elevated app but one still needs to operate in the user space.

regards,
adrian

Comment: Why not get and store the storage location before elevating and then use that? Or is this an application that's always running with elevation?

Comment: And where do you want to store it? Registry doesnt work because of the mentioned behaviour and the program folder itself is neither a good idea.